# How to solve this Darlington circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, darlington

So I have this circuit; it should be a Darlington transistor circuit and I need to find the bias point for it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsUu3C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeHda.jpg

I got to the point where I calculated the Ic1 curent with Kirchoff in the V1 loop which is 1mA (which is a good value) but from there I got stuck.

First I thought as shown here:

[image]

Here the current doesn't go from the emitter of the second transistor but after I had studied more about this type of transistor [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/darlington-transistor.html) the calculations didn't seem to add up, or I am missing something. Any ideas ?

Comment: This design works poorly due to Q2-C too high and thus Q3 Vce near 0V

Comment: If it should be a darlington circuit then why haven't you drawn it that way?

Comment: Would you like to create a differential AC output with better DC bias as your question instead for this Darlingtonish design?

Comment: The circuit in both pictures is the one given in the book(so can't realy modfy it in any way ) and I need  the DC bias-point ( so Ic1 witch I found is 1mA Ic2 Ic3 UCE1 UCE2 and UCE3) done by hand , on paper ... My problem is how the darlington tranzistor ( Q1+Q2) affects the circuit

Comment: I've updated the post with a photo of the initial circuit design ( before pasivization)

Comment: Do you know the beta value for Q1 and Q2 and the Vbe voltage?

Comment: this design is no good and is unstable with Vin, hFE.  if you want to see why , look at Q3 which is saturated

Comment: All the tranzistors are the same with beta = 100

Comment: @VlAdTbK It's not possible to analyze the circuit without a way to convert \$V_\text{BE}=500\:\text{mV}\$ for \$Q_2\$ into \$I_{\text{C}_2}\$. You'll need missing parts to solve that. However, using guessed values \$I_{\text{C}_2}\$ is too small to create much of a drop across \$R_1\$. (I get on order of millivolts, so not much drop at all.) And this does mean that \$Q_3\$ will be saturated. Where did this circuit come from?

Comment: So indeed you can't really solve the circuit as given ... The problem was given from a book of my university professor ( so is not like I invented it or something , is given as homeworked "tested" by himself) ... But let's say you can't calculate Ic2(or atleast say is very small) so then the current that runs threw R5 and R6 can be consider the Ib3 of the third tranzistor right ?

Comment: @jonk so my assumption can be right ?

Comment: @VlAdTbK Assuming I'm right and that \$Q_3\$ is saturated, then its collector and emitter voltages are very close to each other and the collector acts like a voltage source instead of a current source. Also, then, one end of \$R_5\$ is essentially near enough to \$15\:\text{V}\$ that we don't need to worry about the difference. So you can analyze that, in isolation of the rest. The three equations are: \$\frac{V_B}{R_5}+I_B=\frac{15\:\text{V}}{R_5}\$, \$\frac{V_B-500\:\text{mV}}{R_6}+I_C=\frac{15\:\text{V}}{R_6}\$, and \$\frac{V_B-700\:\text{mV}}{R_7}=I_B+I_C\$. Solve for IB, IC, and VB.

Answer (score -1):

You have shown a partial schematic with OPEN LOOP and feedback parts missing which makes the question invalid.

[image]

Comment: That's wrong becouse I've said the circuit that I need to be done is in DC so I posted the circuit after pasivizaiton and scurcircuit of the condesator as can be seen in the imgur photo

Comment: + I posted an image with the full circuit in the question but is not what we need

Comment: Achtung. You have NOT specified what you need for gain, offset and tolerances !!  try this with negative feedback and high gain https://tinyurl.com/y2n2hqcz

Comment: Your "Goal" should be for DC Q points to split Rc, Vce and Ve 3 ways  = 15V/3 if you want a differential output

Comment: Well I am sorry to say but is not that I didn't mention them becouse I didn't want , is becouse I don't have them . All of the data I have I gave in the post . Well , whatever thank you for the model I think I will go with @jonk and say the circuit is not built corectly

Comment: that’s what I said. it is not going to work this way with no feedback same as not built correctly. no specs! no feedback= unstable DC operating point !!

Comment: you can remove Cin if you want DC response.  I have only 40 yrs experience sorry to say I should have to mention.